# Optimize search of a point(latitude,longitude) in a set of polygon(state polygon)

Tags: python, list, sorting, geolocation, point-in-polygon

I stored the polygon data of all the states of USA in a custom object

```
class StateDetails:
    state_name :str
    state_multipolygon :<class 'shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygon'>
```

Now I want to check for a given point which is of type `<class 'shapely.geometry.point.Point'>` it is inside which state. Initially I am using this loop :

```
def get_state_polygon(longitude, latitude, state_details_list):

    point = Point(longitude, latitude)

    def point_in_geofence(point: Point, state_polygon) -> bool:
        return point.within(state_polygon)
    
    for state in state_details_list:
        if point_in_geofence(point,state.state_multipolygon):
            return state.state_name
    return None
```

This is a linear search and is working perfectly as expected. But I want to implement a better approach to use this search. A much efficient and faster method. Can someone please help me with that?

Comment: There are only 50 polygons! You could store them in a quadtree instead of a list if you want to optimise a bit, but with only 50 polygons I'm not sure this optimisation will be worth it.